# ruby not understanding arguments provided to a method

Tags: ruby

I come across this piece of ruby code :

```
def link_to(link_text, url, mode=:path_only)
# You should add "!!" at the beginning if you're directing at the Sinatra url
    if(url_for(url,mode)[0,2] == "!!")
      trimmed_url = url_for(url,mode)[2..-1]
      "<a href=#{trimmed_url}> #{link_text}</a>"
    else
      "<a href=#{url_for(url,mode)}> #{link_text}</a>"
    end  
end  

def url_for url_fragment, mode=:full_url
  case mode
    when :path_only
#cut for brievity. The rest of the function gets rack params and renders full url (or not)
```

I have no clue what this line of code does : `(url_for(url,mode)[0,2] == "!!")`

Comment: Tip: Method calls are like `f(x)` while constructs like `if` are expressed as `if x` or `if (x)` if parentheses are used. The space is a small detail, but it makes it read differently.

Comment: I know. It's not my code. And strangely.... it does work.

Comment: Oh, it does work, it's just that at a glance this looks like a method call to a method named `if`, which it is not. Tools like [Rubocop](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/) can help "lint" your code and find issues like this.

Comment: Did Rubocop stop at Ruby 2.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```rb
url_for(url,mode)[0,2] == "!!"
```

Checks that the first (offset `0`) two characters (`,2`) are equivalent to `"!!"`. This is now something you can express as:

```rb
url_for(url,mode).start_with?("!!")
```

Which might make it easier to understand.

The [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method has two forms relevant to understanding this:

```rb
"hello"[0] # Character index
# => "h"
"hello"[0,1] # Equivalent to above
# => "h"
"hello"[0,2] # Su
# => "he"
```

Comment: The first one is readable if you're used to the notation, but the `start_with?` form is abundantly clear.

Comment: "two forms" might be an understatement. There are also the range, string and regex (optionally with capture group) variants.

Comment: @3limin4t0r True, added some clarification here as to the ones being focused on.